# Output emitted JS files from referenced TS files into single folder, without subfolders

Tags: typescript, grunt-ts

I have a TypeScript file with a reference; the referenced file in turn has other references. When I run the grunt-ts task, a hierarchy of subfolders is created, mirroring the reference hierarchy, and each corresponding JS file is written into a `scripts` subfolder (apparently from the value of the `outDir` option). How can I configure the task so all the emitted JS files end up in a single subfolder?

My configuration looks like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    ts: {
        default: {
            src: ['**/*.ts', "!node_modules/**/*.ts"],
            noImplicitAny: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            target: 'es3',
            fast: 'always',
            outDir: 'scripts'
        }
    }
});
```

I tried specifying an absolute path for `outDir` with the same result.

If I don't specify `outDir`, the JS from referenced TS files is emitted in the location of the TS files, which could be outside the project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Using the flatten option should do the trick:</del>

Output first to a temporary folder:

```
ts: {
    default: {
        src: ['**/*.ts', "!node_modules/**/*.ts"],
        noImplicitAny: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        target: 'es3',
        fast: 'always',
        outDir: 'scripts-temp'
    }
}
```

Then use [grunt-contrib-copy](http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to copy and flatten your intermediate output to your final destination.

```
copy: {
    default: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'scripts-temp/',
        src: '**',
        dest: 'scripts/',
        flatten: true,
        filter: 'isFile',
    },
}
```

Finally, use [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) to delete the temporary folder:

```
clean: {
    default: ['scripts-temp']
}
```

Comment: I tried putting in this option, with the same result. Is there some reference for the `flatten` option, because I couldn't find it [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts)?

Comment: Oops my bad, I did not check on the doc beforehand. Flatten is a common option in other grunt plugins. You could use grunt-contrib-copy (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to copy and flatten your intermediate output to your final destination(requires one more step though)